# I've installed the Canvas LMS; when I run canvas_init start, I get an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, canvas-lms

As stated in the title, I get an error. Specifically, this:

```
Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile
        from /var/www/canvas/Gemfile.d/_before.rb:53
```

I checked bundler:

```
canvas$ bundler -v
```

which returns:

```
Bundler version 1.13.6
```

The relevant section of code is:

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include? ("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

I understand 'git_source' was introduced in Bundler 1.6. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am running into the same problem in my Canvas LMS installation when I try to access the rails console

Comment: @AmyPlant yes - there are some hidden files that don't get moved around properly. We copied the .hidden files over to the /var/canvas directory, specifically .babelrc and .i8n*, babel 6+ now requires a .babelrc file to configure settings. That should fix it.